# Recommender System - Recommend trainings to user based on similar users

Tags: deep-learning

I have read a lot recently about recommendation systems, content based, item based, etc.
And the tutorials always shows the movies ratings dataset as an example.

Where a user rates movies, and then we can suggest movies to another similar user.

My case is a little bit different and I am trying to find a similar example.
In my case lets say I have 2 datasets

1. Training courses with some medatata
2. User profiles with a lot of metadata (department, skills, seniority level, etc)

I could create a matrix of where a user has taken or not a training.

We want to be able to suggest to users  which trainings they should follow based on what similar users have followed.

The recommender system however should take into account the user metadata: job title, department, skills, seniority level.

The examples I have seen so far, dont take into account the user profile features

Can you guide me in the right direction?